# How to remove a tag from an element of BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have a page like this:

```
...
<div class="myclass">
  <p>
    text 1 to keep<span>text 1 to remove</span>and keep this too.
  </p>
  <p>
    text 2 to keep<span>text 2 to remove</span>and keep this too.
  </p>
<div>
```

I.e.: I want to remove all `<span>` tags from any `<p>` element from bs4 (BeautifulSoup in Python3).

Currently this is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

...
text = ""
for tag in soup.find_all(attrs={"class": "myclass"}):
  text += tag.p.text
```

And of course I get all text in spans too...

I read I should use `unwrap()` or `decompose()` but I really do not understand how to use them in practice in my use-case...
All similar Q/A do not help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_text = """\
<div class="myclass">
  <p>
    text 1 to keep<span>text 1 to remove</span>and keep this too.
  </p>
  <p>
    text 2 to keep<span>text 2 to remove</span>and keep this too.
  </p>
<div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")

for span in soup.select("p span"):
    span.replace_with(" ")  # or span.extract()

soup.smooth()

print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```html
<div class="myclass">
 <p>
  text 1 to keep and keep this too.
 </p>
 <p>
  text 2 to keep and keep this too.
 </p>
 <div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this (using CSS selectors instead):

```
for s in soup.select('div.myclass span'):
          s.decompose()
```